# SDL resetting glViewport

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm testing supporting multiple resolutions in an application using SDL2 with OpenGL.  To create my "letterbox" functionality I set my `glViewport` to an appropriate value and everything works perfectly.

However, if I create my window with the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag set, whenever I move my window (after receiving the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED` event) SDL modifies the viewport to the full size of the window, which can be verified by calling `SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize` during the event.

If I do not set `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` when creating the window, the viewport is not reset.  I do believe this to be a bug, but cannot find anything through the SDL bugzilla so I thought to ask if anyone has seen similar behavior.

You may need to have a retina MacBook Pro to experience this behavior.

Comment: Looks like a bug. The best would be to post it to SDL bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what you should be doing anyway: Always re-/set the viewport at the beginning of drawing each frame. As soon as you want to implement a HUD, use framebuffer objects or similar things you'll have to set the viewport (several times) for drawing each frame.